# Paypal button on Odoo (OpenERP 8.0) not working

Tags: paypal, odoo

here is the link of my actual scenario, http://postimg.org/image/3xnib56sj/

In the hilighted function it says "610.00 play safe online" but i can't pay because their is no clickable link.
how can i fix this one, this should be clickable, why iam getting this, idont have anyidea what to do. maybe modify its xml file?

this is its xml

http://pastebin.ca/2832563

any help would be appreciated.